# UIStatusBar become red after using AVAssetExportSession for UIImagePickerController media conversion

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, uistatusbar, avassetexportsession

I am converting the .MOV video i get from UIImagePickerController to the .mp4 format using AVAssetExportSession. Once the conversion is completed I send the data to a server. Everything works fine, except the status bar become red and pulsing after the transmission is completed. If I put the app in background and open it again, then the status bar returns to its normal status again.

This is what I think is the piece of code that causes this behavior:

```
 //I took a video

    __block NSString *messageType;
    __block NSData *messageData;
    __block NSString *messageText;

    [...]

    NSURL *url =  [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

    AVURLAsset *avAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:nil];
    NSArray *compatiblePresets = [AVAssetExportSession exportPresetsCompatibleWithAsset:avAsset];
    NSString *videoPath = nil;
    if ([compatiblePresets containsObject:AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality])
    {
        AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc]initWithAsset:avAsset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough];

        videoPath = [[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:videoDirectory]stringByAppendingPathComponent:tempVideoFileName];
        exportSession.outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoPath];
        NSLog(@"videopath of your mp4 file = %@",videoPath);  // PATH OF YOUR .mp4 FILE
        exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4;

        [exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{

            switch ([exportSession status]) {

                case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:{
                    NSLog(@"Export failed: %@", [[exportSession error] localizedDescription]);
                    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
                    [SVProgressHUD showErrorWithStatus:[[exportSession error] localizedDescription]];
                    }];
                }
                    break;

                case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled:

                    NSLog(@"Export canceled");

                    break;

                case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted:{

                    messageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoPath]];
                    messageText = videoPath;
                    messageType = kMessageTypeVideo;

                    // This method sends asynchronously the data to the server
                    [self sendMediaType:messageType MessageData:messageData MessageText:messageText];

                    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

                }

                    break;

                default:

                    break;

            }


        }];

    }
```

Is there a way to avoid the appearance of the red status bar or at least the way I should use to make it disappear?

Comment: Out of topic?! Come on guys, you can not be serious!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that in some way the recording session of the UIImagePickerController went in conflict with the AVAssetExportSession.

I resolved this issue by converting the video after having dismissed the UIImagePicker controller:

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{

NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
if (CFStringCompare ((__bridge_retained CFStringRef) mediaType, kUTTypeImage, 0)
    == kCFCompareEqualTo) {

    [....]

}
else{
    //Took a video
    NSURL *url =  [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

        [self convertAndSendVideo:url];
    }];

}

}

-(void)convertAndSendVideo:(NSURL *)url{

__block NSString *messageType;
__block NSData *messageData;
__block NSString *messageText;

AVURLAsset *avAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:nil];
NSArray *compatiblePresets = [AVAssetExportSession exportPresetsCompatibleWithAsset:avAsset];
NSString *videoPath = nil;
if ([compatiblePresets containsObject:AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality])
{
    __block AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc]initWithAsset:avAsset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough];

    videoPath = [[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:videoDirectory]stringByAppendingPathComponent:tempVideoFileName];
    exportSession.outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoPath];
    NSLog(@"videopath of your mp4 file = %@",videoPath);  // PATH OF YOUR .mp4 FILE
    exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4;

    [exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{

        switch ([exportSession status]) {

            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:{
                NSLog(@"Export failed: %@", [[exportSession error] localizedDescription]);
                [SVProgressHUD showErrorWithStatus:[[exportSession error] localizedDescription]];
            }
                break;

            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled:

                NSLog(@"Export canceled");

                break;

            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted:{

                messageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoPath]];
                messageText = videoPath;
                messageType = kMessageTypeVideo;

                [self sendMediaType:messageType MessageData:messageData MessageText:messageText];

            }

                break;

            default:

                break;

        }


    }];

}

}
```